# Java RegEx finding strings with anything rather than whitespaces or newline chars

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex expressing any string that contains at least one char that is not a whitespace or the newline char.
For example:

```
"   \n".matches(REEGX) -> false
"hey \n".matches(REGEX) -> true
```

I tried those:

```
"[^\\s\\n]"

"^[^\\s\\n]+$"
```

But both return false for the second example above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Matches should match the whole string. `\h*\S.*` In java `\\h*\\S.*`

Comment: This works thanks! Can you explain why my second regex didn't work?

Comment: Because `^[^\\s\\n]+$` which can be written as `^[^\\s]+$` or `^\\S+$`does not allow matching spaces, but you have a space after `hey `

Answer (score 1):

As `\\s` also matches a newline, you can write `^[^\\s\\n]+$` as `^\\S+$`

The second pattern does not match because there is a space after `hey`  and `.matches` should match the whole string.

If you don't want to cross lines at all, you can match optional leading horizontal whitespace chars, followed by a single non-whitespace char and the rest of the line.

```
\\h*\\S.**
```

If you also want to match possible trailing newlines as you have a newline in the example data:

```
\\h*\\S.*\\R*
```